# No Login Screen in facebook app ..Directly Logged out shown in LogCat

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, logcat, android-logcat

I am trying to implement Facebook-Android Integration for the first time.. i have gone through all the steps which are provided by the facebook in their site of how to do it.. still i am not able to get the login screen of facebook.. Please help me with this problem ..
Thank you

Here i am showing my code and LogCat

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private MainFragment mainFragment;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
        mainFragment = new MainFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
        .commit();
    } else {
        // Or set the fragment from restored state info
        mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();

  // Logs 'install' and 'app activate' App Events.
  AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();

  // Logs 'app deactivate' App Event.
  AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this);
}
```

}

MainFragment.java

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view
            .findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setFragment(this);
    return view;
}

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
        Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

}

Logcat

```
11-18 01:14:49.657: E/ActivityThread(2045): Failed to find provider info for    com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider
11-18 01:14:49.657: E/ActivityThread(2045): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.PlatformProvider
11-18 01:14:49.757: I/Choreographer(2045): Skipped 132 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 01:14:49.887: E/ActivityThread(2045): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
11-18 01:14:49.907: I/MainFragment(2045): Logged out...
11-18 01:14:49.957: I/MainFragment(2045): Logged out...
11-18 01:14:50.037: D/Facebook-publish(2045): FacebookException: No attribution id available to send to server.
11-18 01:18:43.447: D/dalvikvm(2045): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 613K, 18% free 3251K/3940K, paused 32ms, total 36ms
11-18 01:20:15.917: E/ActivityThread(2045): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider
11-18 01:20:15.927: E/ActivityThread(2045): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.PlatformProvider
11-18 01:20:16.027: I/Choreographer(2045): Skipped 104 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 01:20:16.187: I/MainFragment(2045): Logged out...
11-18 01:20:16.207: I/MainFragment(2045): Logged out...
11-18 01:20:16.287: E/ActivityThread(2045): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
11-18 01:20:16.307: D/Facebook-publish(2045): FacebookException: No attribution id available to send to server.
11-18 01:22:13.417: D/dalvikvm(2045): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 509K, 18% free 3254K/3940K, paused 37ms, total 39ms
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.fb_temp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="18"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
</application>
```

Comment: This "Logged Out" is shown everytime.. when i clicked on Log In Button

Comment: one more thing i have to ask.. is it every time a new hash key have to be generated for every app

Comment: show your provider part of manifest.